# Position and centering of the circular shape inside the list cell in CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, position, centering

I have a problem with positioning and centering the round shape in the horizontal list cell.

I've a class for my cicrle:

```
.user-logo {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

And class for the list:

```
.navbar-list {
    @extend ul;
    height: $navbar-height;
    float: right;  

    li {
        float:left;
    }

    a {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
    }

    li a:hover {
        background-color: #111;
    }
}
```

I'm working with react so class usage looks like this:

```
<ul className='navbar-list'>
    <li><NavLink to='/'>New Project</NavLink></li>
    <li><NavLink to='/'>Log Out</NavLink></li>
    <li><NavLink to='/' className='user-logo'>NN</NavLink></li>
</ul>
```

How can I adjust the position of my circular shape inside a cell? For now, the text of my Navbar is well displayed - in the middle of every cell (even the text for my circle), but my circle is still aligned to the upper left corner of the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below CSS code:

```
.user-logo {
  background-color: #4caf50;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.navbar-list {
  height: 50px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.navbar-list li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.navbar-list li a {
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.navbar-list li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

Comment: It works! Of course I had to change padding on margin to keep the circle round, but these options `justify-content` and `align-items` for the list has done all the work. Thank you!

Comment: However, using your solution, is there any way to set up a padding for the cells, but reset it for my cicrle? Because I need padding for my text-cells, but I would keep my cicrle round. The settings `padding-right: 0; padding-left: 0;` for cicrle does not change anything because of the setting for the `a` element, which stretches my shape horizontaly.

Comment: Yes, instead of flex you can use position:relative to .user-logo then wrap NN using span tag. For the span tag use position: absolute, top: 50%, left: 50%, display: block, transform: translate (-50%,-50%)

Comment: This way didn't fully solved my problem, because I still couldn't add any padding to my list elements (it was still stretching my circle). But I took your advice and finally used the span tags for the text cells in my list and then added padding only for the span tags. Now I have a round circle and padding on the text items in the list. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make the parent element into a flexbox by doing:

`li{ display: flex; }`

For more info on flexbox css you can have a look [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) or other tutorials online.

Otherwise, make sure your circular shape has `display: inline-block` so that you can control its vertical positioning with margins and try to optimize with even top and bottom margins on the circular shape or top and bottom paddings on the parent element.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I tried your idea and thank you for showing me the flex display option. Unfortunately, it only centered my circle vertically, so the shape is still stuck to the top of the list cell. I also tried to play with the margin and padding. The problem is that if I do this on the style definition for my circle, I only affect the text inside it ("NN"), but if I change these style options for "a" it affects all the cells, so the circle is still not in the same line as the other cells. Any ideas?